# Need to get timed input to break out of loop

Tags: python, loops, timeout

I have a loop that times user input, when the loop is done I want to break out of it:

```
import sys
import time
import msvcrt
from random import randint
import random

def time_input(caption, timeout=3):
    start_time = time.time()
    sys.stdout.write('%s: ' % (caption))
    input = ''
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            chr = msvcrt.getche()
            if ord(chr) == 13:
                break
            elif ord(chr) >= 32:
                input += chr
        if len(input) == 0 and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            break
```

Where this loop is called, is here:

```
def battle(animal, weapon, health):
    print "To try to kill the {};" \
          " you must press the correct key" \
          " when it appears on the screen." \
          " Press enter when ready".format(animal)
    raw_input()

    keys = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    animal_health = 100

    while health > 0:
        while True:

            if animal == 'mountain lion':
                animal_damage = randint(27, 97)
                animal_output = "The mountain lion slashes at you doing {} damage!".format(animal_damage)
            else:
                animal_damage = randint(10, 25)
                animal_output = "The {} slashes at you doing {} damage!".format(animal, animal_damage)

            correct_key = random.choice(keys)
            print "Enter: {}".format(correct_key)
            to_eval = time_input('> ')

            if to_eval == correct_key:
                damage = weapon_info(weapon, animal_health)
                print damage
                animal_health -= damage
                print "The {} has {} health remaining".format(animal, animal_health)
                if animal_health <= 0:
                    win_battle(animal, weapon)

            else:
                print animal_output
                health -= animal_damage
                print "You have {} health remaining".format(health)
                if health <= 0:
                    lose_battle(animal)
                    break

battle('mountain lion', 'knife', 100)
```

How can I get this loop to break out when all the correct keys have been pressed and the health is 0 or less?

As of now it does this:

To try to kill the mountain lion; you must press the correct key when it appears
 on the screen. Press enter when ready

```
Enter: h
h: h
You slash at them with your knife doing 20
20
The mountain lion has 80 health remaining
Enter: a
a: a
You slash at them with your knife doing 24
24
The mountain lion has 56 health remaining
Enter: j
j: j
You slash at them with your knife doing 23
23
The mountain lion has 33 health remaining
Enter: p
p: p
You slash at them with your knife doing 10
10
The mountain lion has 23 health remaining
Enter: k
k: k
You slash at them with your knife doing 26
26
The mountain lion has -3 health remaining
You pick up the dead mountain lion and start walking back to camp.
You found extra meat!
Enter: h  # Just keeps going
h: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battle.py", line 97, in <module>
    battle('mountain lion', 'knife', 100)
  File "battle.py", line 31, in battle
    to_eval = time_input(correct_key)
  File "C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\python\game\settings.py", line 36, in time
_input
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return` to escape the `battle`-function.  My guess is right here

```
if animal_health <= 0:
    win_battle(animal, weapon)
    return     <------------------------------
```

Maybe you want to return your current hp if the battle was successful?  This should be easy by simply returning health instead of nothing, i.e. `return healt` instead of just `return`

You probably want to do the same thing after loosing a battle as well, but without returning any health, i.e. `return 0`?

Comment: You're a freaking genius! I was stuck on this for at least 2 hours

Comment: As long as it helped you I'm happy :)